# Java travando no windows server

Tags: java

Pessoal estou com um problema, tenho uma app rodando no server 2012 ,o problema é q simplesmente depois de uns 2 dias o java trava e nao me da nenhum erro , tenho q finalizar o java e abrir novamente ai ele volta a funcionar , estou usando o glassfish , alguem ja viu esse erro ?

Comment: Não sou expert em Java EE. Mas você poderia por mais algumas informações sobre o sistema. Por exemplo, se usa alguma framework, qual banco de dados, versão do GlassFish... Mais uma coisa, já tentou com Tomcat?

Comment: bom , banco de dados firebird , uso hibernate jpa e jsf

Comment: Qual a versão do GlassFlish? Já tentou com Tomcat?

Comment: to usando o glassfish 4 , nao testei com o tomcat ainda

Comment: Qual a configuração da maquina utilizada?

Comment: é um i7 com 16 gb de memoria

Comment: Cara se a sugestão do @PedroSoares não funcionar, acredito que você irá precisar colher um pouco mais de dados sobre esse problema. Conheço pouco do Glassfish mas, se lembro bem, ele tem um console de administração com ferramentas para monitoramento. Acho que pode ser uma ferramenta legal para entender o que está acontecendo.

Comment: O primeiro passo é você monitorar o que está acontecendo na aplicação durante o travamento. É um crash da JVM, isto é, processo finaliza do nada? A aplicação simplesmente para de responder? Quanta memória ela está consumindo no momento do travamento? Você pode usar ferramentas como JVisualVM que vêm no JDK para monitorar a aplicação em tempo real. Extraia um *thread dump*, isto é, uma imagem dos stack traces de todas as threads executando no momento do travamento.

Comment: Enfim, você precisa iniciar uma investigação e não ficar chutando o problema. Isso pode ser causado por qualquer atualização que alguém fez no sistema, atualização em alguma biblioteca, aumento abrupto dos dados carregados em memória (talvez algum usuário tenha importado milhares de registros novos no banco) e assim por diante. Isso ocorre quando alguém executa alguma função específica?

Answer (score 1):

Não sou expert em Java EE, mas pelo que andei lendo pela internet, algumas versões do GlassFish acontece exatamente o mesmo problema, mas ninguém sabe o porque. Então vou resumir os passos que encontrei na internet e verifique se irá funcionar no seu caso.
01) Atualize seu GlassFish, se for a ultima versão, volte para uma anterior.
02) Verifique se possui mais de 2gb de memória RAM, algumas pessoas relatam problema com 2gb de RAM com GlassFish no Windows 7/Server.
03) Comesse a usar o Tomcat.
04) Verifique como estão as rotinas do software caso seja de desenvolvimento seu, existem boas praticas que evitam esse problema, como por exemplo, não fazer consulta ao banco em GETs e SETs.

Foi só isso que achei na internet, como disse antes, não sou expert em Java, só estou querendo ajudar.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, amanha vou testar e ja retorno o resultado